# How can I make tag list in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tags

I want to create a list of tags, what I'll take from an array, but how can I stylize it as:

[image]

inside of bubbles and auto place in the next row if the line is full. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/xhacker/TagListView

Comment: Or this: https://github.com/OskarZhang/TagListView

Comment: @RafałSroka I'm using it, but I have an issue. How can I make UIView responsive?

Answer (score 8):

Please read this library link giving below it has awesome and custom tag design all the things you required for your design.

> https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Here is how to use it.

1. add its cocoapods [pod "TagListView"].
2. Create a view on which you wanna to show your selected tags and constraint it.
3. change your view class name to "TagListView".
4. set delegate on viewDidLoad(). [yourView.delegate = self]
5. now you use it. eg.

> yourView.addTag("Name on Tag")
>       or yourView.addTags(["Name on Tag First","Name on Tag second","Name on tag third",.....and so on])

Comment: Is there a similar class for MacOS instead of iOS?

Comment: For MacOs you can https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/token-fields

Answer (score 2):

[image]I have implemented a **simple and customizable tag list** view in swift using a collection view.

[Here](https://github.com/shamiul110107/TagView-in-swift) is my github link.

Comment: Best solution without pod