# SwiftUI LazyGrid dynamic column width

Tags: swiftui

How can I make the Grid item width dynamic so that it takes the width of the text?

Using the code below the text is truncated, I would like all the text to be displayed without the truncation, taking into account the variable text lengths.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let data = ["O Menino","The Boy", "The Girl", "A Menina","Mae","Mother"]
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum:50))
        
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
       
        ScrollView{
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 20){
                ForEach(data, id: \.self){ item in
                    VStack{
                        Text(item).lineLimit(1)
                    }.background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange wish for vertical grid... the cumulative width of your content is much wider than screen width, so what would you expect, of course text will be truncated.

Comment: @Asperi you missed the point…

Answer (score 6):

It is VGrid, it grows vertically filling columns. In your case it is only one column.

If you want to fit all those content in screen, you'd need to increase number of grid columns, like

```
let data = ["O Menino","The Boy", "The Girl", "A Menina","Mae","Mother"]
let layout = Array(repeating: GridItem(.adaptive(minimum:50)), count: 4)
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I guess this is what I am trying to acheieve, as you can see the number of columns varies depending on the row content, I have been using a UIRepresentable collection view at the moment but was hoping for a more native swiftUI approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625895/how-can-i-make-tag-list-in-swift/45734125

Comment: I assume the following posts might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876712/12299030 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103264/12299030