# Creating an editable list of tags

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to replicate what Simplenote does with its ability to add tags: you write a tag, press space or "next" and the tag is created with a pill around it. You can then add another tag with the same method.

Example

[image]

Displaying each tag as a pill is the easy part:

```
//displaying the tags in a pil-like shape
@State var tags: [String] = []

HStack{
    ForEach(tags, id: \.self){tag in
        Button(action: {}) {
            HStack {
                Text(tag)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .cornerRadius(.infinity)
    }
}
```

Now, adding new tags is something I'm struggling with. I tried with a `TextField` but, I don't know how to get each word entered and display them as a pill in the same line. Then I tried with an `HStack` hoping to build a list or something and display the words horizontally, and then the `TextField` right next to the list of words.

I was told that this is not a code writing service, and I'm not looking for you to write my code, I just need ideas. I can write the code, but I don't know how to even begin to think about this.

Thanks

EDIT:

I checked:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-to-a-list-of-words

https://iosexample.com/tag/tags/

[Implementing a tag list in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129890/implementing-a-tag-list-in-swiftui)

[How can I make tag list in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625895/how-can-i-make-tag-list-in-swift)

[SwiftUI a Tag View in the middle of a Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847289/swiftui-a-tag-view-in-the-middle-of-a-text)

And https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Tj6xp1DOj0

Oh, and

https://www.appcoda.com/learnswiftui/swiftui-gridlayout.html

https://swiftobc.com/repo/HappyIosDeveloper-SwiftUI-TagView-swift-ui

I *know* how to display the tags, I just don't know how to create them using a single line where the textfield and the tags live together. but I guess Stack Overflow is **not** the place to ask, right?

Comment: I get you are getting frustrated but I was going to add an idea of what I think you want but the very first link you posted for hacking with swift is the "idea" I was thinking about you have not clearly defined what you issue is, it isn't that I don't want to help, you have not defined what you need help with, anything else posted here is a guess.

Comment: @loremipsum it is clearly defined in the question: I know how to display the tags, I just don't know how to create them using a single line where the textfield and the tags live together.

Comment: look at the `onSubmit` line in the hacking with swift link you posted. There is no better solution than that for what you are saying.

Comment: @loremipsum added my own answer below. have a good one.

Comment: You too. I am glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created my own. It's brutish and it has a lot of bugs, but hey...
Add and remove tags. It's not pretty.

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
        Spacer()

        Divider()
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                Button(action: {
                    removeTag(tag: tag)
                }) {
                    Text(tag)
                        .padding(1)
                        .lineSpacing(10)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
            TextField("Tag...", text: $newTag).disableAutocorrection(true).onSubmit(addNewTag).submitLabel(.done)
        }
    }
}

// check if tag is already there
func isOriginal(word: String) -> Bool {
    !tags.contains(word)
}

// add new tag
func addNewTag() {
    // lowercase and trim the word, to make sure we don't add duplicate words with case differences
    let tagWord = newTag.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    // exit if the remaining string is empty
    guard tagWord.count > 0 else { return }

    // exit if the tag was already used
    guard isOriginal(word: tagWord) else {
        newTag = ""
        return
    }

    tags.insert(tagWord, at: 0)
    newTag = ""
}

func removeTag(tag: String) {
    print("removing " + tag)
    if let index = tags.firstIndex(of: tag) {
        tags.remove(at: index)
        disabled = false
    }
}
```